# Anaconda-navigator crashes when launch on Mac

Tags: anaconda

I just downloaded the latest version of anaconda-navigator on Mac, but when I tried to open the application, the dock icon appears and then disappears directly. It doesn't have any error message.

I tried the command line 
  `anaconda-navigator --reset`
It has the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last) Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Monday123/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 199, in <module>
from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/Monday123/anaconda3/bin/anaconda-navigator", line 7, in <module>
from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main
File "/Users/Monday123/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/app/main.py", line 22, in <module>
from anaconda_navigator.utils.conda import is_conda_available
File "/Users/Monday123/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/utils/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
from qtpy.QtGui import QIcon
File "/Users/Monday123/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/qtpy/__init__.py", line 205, in <module>
raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found`
```

Answer (score 1):

Please update to the latest version of Navigator to include
the latest fixes.

Open a terminal (on Linux or Mac) or the Anaconda Command Prompt (on windows)
and type:

```
conda update conda

conda update anaconda-navigator

conda update navigator-updater
```